# Why did Doc give Baby the gloves?

Tags: plot-explanation, baby-driver

In *Baby Driver (2017)*, before the second heist, Doc gives Baby a pair of gloves and Baby disposes of them after the heist. What was the point of giving him gloves at all?

It makes sense to wear them not to leave any fingerprints behind, but why didn't he have them in the first heist where it was clearly visible he had no gloves?

Why the sudden change? What was the point of not having gloves in one heist and having them in another? Why didn't they stick with some approach eather gloves every heist or no gloves at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## They were a gift

The gloves have nothing to do with fingerprints, Doc is giving Baby a gift of driving gloves...

[image]

> A driving glove is a hand covering, typically constructed of very thin, soft leather, used to give a driver increased control of the vehicle through enhanced grip of the steering wheel and gear stick. The grain present on the leather and the pores present in the leather give the gloves the unique ability to assist the wearer as he or she grips the steering wheel and gear stick. As soft as a leather glove may be, its pores and grain provide a level of friction when "gripped" against an item or surface.
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_glove)</sup>

### ...but...

Recall that Baby is only working with/for Doc to pay off a debt...not by choice. He has no emotional connection or relationship with Doc.

After finally paying off the debt and completing his final assignment from Doc...he's **free**.

So he strips off the gloves as an indication of the detachment from Doc's influence.